# call different functions based on parameter

Tags: python

Looking for suggestions to improve this bit of code. Basically I want to create a generic verify function  based on param ?

```
def verify(self, param, val):        
        if param == type
            self.assertEqual(self.tm.get.type, val)
        if param == size
            self.assertEqual(self.tm.get.size, val)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use getattr:

```
def verify(self, param, val):
    self.assertEqual(getattr(self.tm.get, param), val)
```